# Check if key exists in hash in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes for instance:

```
array = [{apple => 10},{banana => 5},{pear => 1}]
```

I want to do something like the following (partly pseudocode)

```
fruit = "Orange"
if array.anyhash.key = fruit do |fruit|
    array << {fruit => 1}
else
   array.hashwithkey(fruit).value += 1
end
```

Is there a way to do this simply or do I have to do nested each statements?

Comment: Yes, use one Hash instead of array of hashes ;)

Comment: Is there any reason to have an array of hashes instead of a single hash?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by your pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use one hash:

```
hash = {'apple' => 10,'banana' => 5,'pear' => 1}
p hash['apple']
```

**OUTPUT**:
10

Comment: Thanks. I feel a bit stupid. Shows what happens when I don't write code for a couple of months.

Comment: With `hash` defined as above, I think OP was looking for `if hash.has_key('apple')..`. @lpsum: since `hash['apple']` => nil if `'apple'` is not a key, you could use `if(hash['apple'])...` but that's a problem in situations where the hash may contain, say, `:a=>nil`, in which case `hash[:a]` => nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{'apple' => 10},{'banana' => 5},{'pear' => 1}]
fruit = 'orange'
match = a.find {|h| h.member? fruit }
if match
  match[fruit] += 1
else
  a << {fruit: 1}
end
```

It's better to use simple hash.

```
a = {'apple' => 10, 'banana' => 5, 'pear' => 1}
fruit = 'orange'
a[fruit] = a.fetch(fruit, 0) + 1
```